# Swift Get Text Selection Events for UIWebView in Cordova Ionic Application

Tags: swift, cordova, ionic-framework, scroll, contextmenu

Currently, I have a Cordova ionic-angularjs application where I want to freeze the scrolling while the user is selecting text (I enable the context menu by following [this little hack](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-make-text-selectable/4384/2))

Right now, I have the Swift native code capturing `UIMenuController.didShowMenuNotification` and `UIMenuController.didHideMenuNotification` events, which, in turn, dispatches respective javascript document events to be handled by the web application and freezes the `$ionicScrollDelegate`, as shown below. This works great and the scroll is frozen upon display of the context menu, however, if the user wants to expand/contract the selection, the context menu disappears temporarily during the expansion/contraction, which unfreezes the scroll view until the context menu reappears after the user lifts their finger. Would it be possible to get the range of selected text instead of basing the freeze of the scroll view on the context menu display state, so that the scroll view is frozen until no text is selected?

**CDVContextMenu.swift**

```swift
@objc(CDVContextMenu)
class CDVContextMenu: CDVPlugin {

    typealias This = CDVContextMenu
    static var sharedCommandDelegate: CDVCommandDelegate?
    var contextMenuVisible = false

    override func pluginInitialize() {
        super.pluginInitialize()
        This.sharedCommandDelegate = commandDelegate
        NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(self,
                         selector: #selector(menuDidShow),
                         name: UIMenuController.didShowMenuNotification,
                         object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(self,
                         selector: #selector(menuDidHide),
                         name: UIMenuController.didHideMenuNotification,
                         object: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Event Handlers

    @objc
    func menuDidShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        This.sharedCommandDelegate?.evalJs("document.dispatchEvent(new Event('contextMenuDidShow'));")
        contextMenuVisible = true
    }

    @objc
    func menuDidHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        This.sharedCommandDelegate?.evalJs("document.dispatchEvent(new Event('contextMenuDidHide'));")
        contextMenuVisible = false
    }

}
```

**index.js**

```js
document.addEventListener('contextMenuDidShow', function() {
  $ionicScrollDelegate.freezeScroll(true);
})

document.addEventListener('contextMenuDidHide', function() {
  $ionicScrollDelegate.freezeScroll(false);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around by doing this in the javascript without the need for a plugin:

```js
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.freezeScroll(true);
});
document.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.freezeScroll(false);
})
```